# Rotating images generically

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

So this is working well for me so far but I do not want to make a new method for every image on the page. How do I get the control "Card" in the codebehind method when it is called so I can use the same method on every image button. Is there a better way to do this? All I want is to rotate an image 90 deg when clicked and, when clicked again rotate the image back. The problem is that I want to use only one method that will rotate any image.

```
protected void Card_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Card.CssClass == "rotate90Large")
        {
            Card.CssClass = "";
        }
        else
        {
            Card.CssClass = "rotate90Large";
        }
    }
```

.aspx

```
<style type="text/css"> 
    .rotate90Large{-ms-transform: rotate(90deg); margin-left:45px; } 

</style>

<asp:ImageButton ID="Card" ImageUrl="Graphics/image.jpg" runat="server" onclick="Card_Click"  />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casting the sender should be sufficient, and you can subscribe all image buttons to the same click event, in your case `Card_Click`

```
protected void Card_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    ImageButton img = (ImageButton)sender;

    if (img.CssClass == "rotate90Large")
    {
        img.CssClass = "";
    }
    else
    {
        img.CssClass = "rotate90Large";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So write a function that takes an image as parameter, rotates it and returns it as the return value.... ??
Then call that function passing whichever image you want to rotate.

Perhaps even create it as an extension method

Comment: How do you take an image as a parameter in an On_Click image button method. That is my question.